# Fade effect blinks first time it's triggered, but then works as intended

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm experiencing an unwanted visual effect when changing tabs. What I want is for .`policyCentre__content` sections to fade out slowly, and to fade in the relevant section slowly too. However, when you change tab initially, if it's the first time the matching `policyCentre__content` is loaded, it will blink in, rather than fade.

See steps to reproduce:

1. Run the below demo (you will start off with "tab 1" active.
2. Click "tab 2" and watch the content appear ("tab 1" content fades out, but content for "tab 2" just appears.
3. Click back onto "tab 1", and the content disappears and appears as intended.
4. Click back onto "tab 2" and it now works as intended.

Unsure why the 2nd step initially just makes the content appear?

```js
$(function() {

  function showContent(val){
    $(".policyCentre__content.active").fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
      $(".policyCentre__content[data-item='" + val + "']").addClass('active').fadeIn(500, function() {
        locked = false;
      })
    });
  }

  // prevent the UI from getting over-clicked
  let locked = false;

  $(".policyCentre__label:first, .policyCentre__content:first").addClass("active");

  $('.policyCentre__label').click(function() {
    if (locked) return;
    locked = true;
    var id = $(this).attr('data-item');
    $(".policyCentre__label").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    showContent(id);
  });
  
  });
```

```css
.policyCentre {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 60px 0;
}
.policyCentre__label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.policyCentre__label:hover, .policyCentre__label.active {
  color: orange;
}
.policyCentre__content {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.policyCentre__content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="policyCentre">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">

      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="policyCentre__tabs">
          <span class="policyCentre__label" data-item="tab-1">Tab 1</span>
          <span class="policyCentre__label" data-item="tab-2">Tab 2</span>
          <span class="policyCentre__label" data-item="tab-3">Tab 3</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="policyCentre__content" data-item="tab-1">Copy for tab 1</div>
        <div class="policyCentre__content" data-item="tab-2">Copy for tab 2</div>
        <div class="policyCentre__content" data-item="tab-3">Copy for tab 3</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because you have this rule in your CSS:

```
.policyCentre__content.active {
  display:block;
}
```

...which is forcing the div to show immmediately (rather than animate in) when you apply the 'active' class. I removed that rule and instead used your hide/show function to show the first tab (rather than relying on that display:block css rule). Because (for this first transition) we aren't hiding anything, I broke your hide/show function into 2 (transitionContent() and showContent()) so we could just call `showContent()` initially.

```js
$(function() {
  function transitionContent(val) {
    $(".policyCentre__content.active").fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
      showContent(val)
    });
  }

  function showContent(val) {
    $(".policyCentre__content[data-item='" + val + "']").addClass('active').fadeIn(500, function() {
      locked = false;
    })
  }

  showContent('tab-1')
  // prevent the UI from getting over-clicked
  let locked = false;

  $(".policyCentre__label:first, .policyCentre__content:first").addClass("active");

  $('.policyCentre__label').click(function() {
    if (locked) return;
    locked = true;
    var id = $(this).attr('data-item');
    $(".policyCentre__label").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    transitionContent(id);
  });

});
```

```css
.policyCentre {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.policyCentre__label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.policyCentre__label:hover,
.policyCentre__label.active {
  color: orange;
}

.policyCentre__content {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.policyCentre__content.active {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="policyCentre">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">

      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="policyCentre__tabs">
          <span class="policyCentre__label" data-item="tab-1">Tab 1</span>
          <span class="policyCentre__label" data-item="tab-2">Tab 2</span>
          <span class="policyCentre__label" data-item="tab-3">Tab 3</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="policyCentre__content" data-item="tab-1">Copy for tab 1</div>
        <div class="policyCentre__content" data-item="tab-2">Copy for tab 2</div>
        <div class="policyCentre__content" data-item="tab-3">Copy for tab 3</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ah I see! `fadeIn()` will add `display` property once it has completed its transition, whereas my `css` was causing it to add the `display` property immediately. Thanks for explaining :)